# Auto SARIMA model in R

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

Is there a `auto.sarima` function in R programming. I know there is `auto.arima` function in r programming. But I am not sure if there is also `auto.sarima` function or program. If there is a way to generate the order of p,d,q and P,D,Q values, please let me know. I appreciate you help.

```
> data("departures")
> auto.arima(Enrolled_COUNT, D=1)
Series: Enrolled_COUNT 
ARIMA(0,1,1) 

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.4169
s.e.   0.1777
```

Comment: Doesn't auto.arima cover this already?

Comment: auto.arima generates only p,d,q values but not seasonal order (P,D,Q) values. I am trying to find out if there is a way to auto generate those values.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Seems like P,D,Q are there to me https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.12/topics/auto.arima

Comment: Added my program and results. As you can see just the ARIMA order was generated but not the seasonal order.

Comment: Just because you didn't end on a seasonal model doesn't mean it didn't consider seasonal models.

Comment: Attach a reproducible example for the data `departures`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `auto.arima` can detect the seasonal part by using the parameter `seasonal = T` as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37400899/11570343).

Comment: Hi, Yes it works, thank you. Great to have you here!!

Comment: but though I have got some warning after I used ```seasonal=T```. Any idea why? ```Warning message:
The chosen seasonal unit root test encountered an error when testing for the second difference.
From stl(): series is not periodic or has less than two periods
1 seasonal differences will be used. Consider using a different unit root test```

Comment: you can see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/404737/249601).